# Error while trying to make a RabbitMQ C-master project

Tags: c, makefile, cmake, rabbitmq-c

I am trying to build my own project, i.e., smart_parking using RabbitMQ C-master. The link to the C APIs is:
https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c

I made a folder with the name smart_parking in the rabbitmq folder. I also wrote the CMakeLists.txt files and edited the Makefile.am as follows:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# vim:set ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 et:
include_directories(${LIBRABBITMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if (WIN32)
    set(PLATFORM_DIR win32)
else (WIN32)
    set(PLATFORM_DIR unix)
endif (WIN32)

set(COMMON_SRCS
    utils.h
    utils.c
    ${PLATFORM_DIR}/platform_utils.c
    )

add_executable(client_1 client_1.c ${COMMON_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(client_1 ${RMQ_LIBRARY_TARGET})

add_executable(client_2 client_2.c ${COMMON_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(client_2 ${RMQ_LIBRARY_TARGET})

add_executable(client_3 client_3.c ${COMMON_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(client_3 ${RMQ_LIBRARY_TARGET})

add_executable(client_4 client_4.c ${COMMON_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(client_4 ${RMQ_LIBRARY_TARGET})
```

Makefile.am:

```
if SMART_PARKING
noinst_LTLIBRARIES += smart_parking/libutils.la

smart_parking_libutils_la_SOURCES = \
    smart_parking/utils.c \
    smart_parking/utils.h
smart_parking_libutils_la_CFLAGS = $(AM_CFLAGS)

if OS_UNIX
smart_parking_libutils_la_SOURCES += smart_parking/unix/platform_utils.c
endif

if OS_WIN32
smart_parking_libutils_la_SOURCES += smart_parking/win32/platform_utils.c
smart_parking_libutils_la_CFLAGS += -I$(top_srcdir)/tools/win32/msinttypes
endif

noinst_PROGRAMS = \
    smart_parking/client_1 \
    smart_parking/client_2 \
    smart_parking/client_3 \
    smart_parking/client_4 

smart_parking_client_1_SOURCES = smart_parking/client_1.c
smart_parking_client_1_LDADD = \
    smart_parking/libutils.la \
    librabbitmq/librabbitmq.la

smart_parking_client_2_SOURCES = smart_parking/client_2.c
smart_parking_client_2_LDADD = \
    smart_parking/libutils.la \
    librabbitmq/librabbitmq.la

smart_parking_client_3_SOURCES = smart_parking/client_3.c
smart_parking_client_3_LDADD = \
    smart_parking/libutils.la \
    librabbitmq/librabbitmq.la

smart_parking_client_4_SOURCES = smart_parking/client_4.c
smart_parking_client_4_LDADD = \
    smart_parking/libutils.la \
    librabbitmq/librabbitmq.la
endif
```

But when I try to make the project, I get the following error:

```
GEN      tools/doc/amqp-publish.1
usage: xmlto [OPTION]... FORMAT XML
OPTIONs are:
  -v              verbose output (-vv for very verbose)
  -x stylesheet   use the specified stylesheet instead of choosing one
  -m fragment     use the XSL fragment to customize the stylesheet
  -o directory    put output in the specified directory instead of
                  the current working directory
  -p postprocopts pass option to postprocessor
  --extensions    turn on stylesheet extensions for this tool chain
  --noautosize    do not autodetect paper size via locales or paperconf
  --noclean       temp files are not deleted automatically
                  (good for diagnostics)
  --noextensions  do not use passivetex/fop extensions
  --searchpath    colon-separated list of fallback directories
  --skip-validation
                  do not attempt to validate the input before processing
  --stringparam paramname=paramvalue
                  pass a named parameter to the stylesheet from the
                  command line
  --with-fop      use fop for formatting (if fop available)
  --with-dblatex  use dblatex for formatting (if dblatex available)

Available FORMATs depend on the type of the XML file (which is
determined automatically).

For documents of type "docbook":
awt  dvi  epub  fo  html  htmlhelp  html-nochunks  javahelp  man  mif  pcl  pdf  ps  svg  text  txt  xhtml  xhtml-nochunks

For documents of type "xhtml1":
awt  dvi  fo  mif  pcl  pdf  ps  svg  txt

For documents of type "fo":
awt  dvi  mif  pcl  pdf  ps  svg  txt
make[1]: *** [tools/doc/amqp-publish.1] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/l4tmm/Desktop/Smart parking simulation in C/rabbitmq-c'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: If you're going to add your project to the rabbitmq-c build-system, you only need to add it to the `CMakeLists.txt` or the `Makefile.am` file, not both.

Answer (score 1):

The `usage: xmlto [OPTION]... FORMAT XML` error is due to xmlto being called incorrectly from the build script.  Disable doc generation by passing in `--disable-docs` to the configure script.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on how to do this?

Comment: When running `./configure` add the `--disable-docs` flag, e.g., `./configure --disable-docs`

Comment: That helped.. Thanks! @alanxz